# What is that? Cell or Table?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I am finishing my first app adding an *About Us* section. I want to create something like this there:
[image]

I want to insert the FAQ and website link but what is that? Is a custom cell? a Table?

Now I am using a simple button but I think that the option in the picture is more.

It's probably something very simple, please help.

Answer (score 3):

That is a simple grouped section in `UITableView`, though cell is more likely to be custom one.